# Google Sheets sharing based on dynamic list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I'm betting this is way beyond Sheets' capabilities, but my workgroup is large and changes frequently.  It would be ideal to be able to share Sheets documents based on a column of values in another (or even the same) sheet.

For example,

```
Column A   B
       x   ashley@blah.com
           bob@blah.com
       x   charlie@blah.com
```

A check of column A would yield 'ashley' and 'charlie' for the sharing list.

Even remotely possible?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle sharing files with large and dynamic groups on Google Drive is by using Google Groups, but it's also possible to do the way you are thinking by using Google Apps Script or the Google Drive API and the Google Sheets API

To use a group from Google Groups to handle sharing files, share the files with the group by adding its email address.

To use Google Apps Script you have to create a Google Apps Script project, add the code and run it. This could be done directly from the Google Apps Script editor, by using an inserted drawing as button, using a custom menu, sidebar or dialog.

To use Google Drive API and Google Sheets API you should write program by using a programming language that support calling APIs

Related

- [Share permissions set for a group is not effective if a new user is added to the group](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37425/88163)
- [Do a user's access permissions to a document change if they are removed from the Google Group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110512/88163)